# Ячейки в PL/SQL

Tags: sql

Можно ли средствами PL/SQL организовать вычитание/сложение/умножение одной ячейки из/на другую?
То есть, например, имеем таблицу 10 на 8, можно ли из первой строки вычесть шестую строку, из второй седьмую и тд, так, чтобы во всех столбцах были верные значения (как в Excel)?

Мне нужно вычитать строки, а не столбцы. Пример:

```
 data        stat      count      
----------  ----------  ---------- 
28.08          1         15 
28.08          2         45
28.08          3         100
27.08          1         10 
27.08          2         40
27.08          3         95
```

Моя цель получить таблицу

```
stat        count      
----------  ----------    
1               5   
2               5  
3               5
```

Comment: Count - это столбец, собственно ты его и вычитаешь. изначально, из постановки задачи не понятно какую таблицу на выходе ты хочешь получить.

Comment: Какой результат ты хочешь получить если исходные данные будут такие:

data        stat      count      
----------  ----------  ---------- 
28.08          1         15 
28.08          2         45
28.08          3         100
27.08          1         10 
27.08          2         40
27.08          3         95
26.08          1         5 
26.08          2         35
26.08          3         90

Comment: Не в исходные, а в новую таблицу, полученную из исходной

Answer (score 3):

Можно, используя аналитические функции:

> LEAD(выpaжeниe, <смещение>,
> <стандартное значение>)  Функция LEAD позволяет обращаться к
> строкам, следующим за текущей.
>
> LAG(выражение, <смещение>,
> <стандартное значение>) Функция LAG
> дает доступ к другим строкам
> результирующего множества, избавляя от
> необходимости выполнять
> самосоединения. Она позволяет работать
> с курсором как с массивом. Можно
> ссылаться на строки, предшествующие
> текущей строке в группе.
>
> Смещение - это положительное целое
> число со стандартным значением 1
> (предыдущая строка). Стандартное
> значение возвращается, если индекс
> выходит за пределы окна (для первой
> строки группы будет возвращено
> стандартное значение).

Пример:

```
create table temp_calc as select 1 as f1, 2 as f2, 0 as gr from dual where 1=0;

insert into temp_calc values (5, 3, 0)
insert into temp_calc values (3, 1, 0);
insert into temp_calc values (-2, 0, 0);

insert into temp_calc values (4, -2, 1)
insert into temp_calc values (2, -1, 1);

Собственно сам запрос:    
select c.f1-lead(c.f1, 1, 0) over (partition by c.gr order by c.gr) as f1_result,
       c.f2-lead(c.f2, 1, 0) over (partition by c.gr order by c.gr) as f2_result,
       c.gr, c.f1, c.f2
from temp_calc c

Главная функция здесь:
     lead(c.f1, --столбец, который нужно вычесть из текущего поля
          1, --смещение, относительно текущей строки
          0) --значение, возвращаемое если строки по смещению не существует строки
```

Здесь главное правильно сформировать конструкцию (partition by [c.gr](http://c.gr) order by [c.gr](http://c.gr)) - которая непосредственно устанавливает порядок строк(order by [c.gr](http://c.gr)) в группе(partition by [c.gr](http://c.gr))
их тех строк, которым не найдена строка по смещению по-умолчанию вычитается 0 - последний параметр функции LEAD.

Answer (score 1):

Простые арифметические  операции над данными:

```
SQL> create table temp_calc as select 1 as f1, 2 as f2 from dual where 1=0;
Table created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values (5, 3);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values (4, -2);
1 row created.
SQL> select * from temp_calc;
        F1         F2
---------- ----------
         5          3
         4         -2

SQL> select (f1+f2) as add_value, (f1-f2) as sub_value, (f1*f2) as mul_value from temp_calc;
 ADD_VALUE  SUB_VALUE  MUL_VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------
         8          2         15
         2          6         -8
```

Если Вам надо работать одновременно сразу с несколькими строками, и каждую из них можно уникально идентифицировать, то можно сделать так:

```
SQL> select (t1.f1 + t2.f2) as mul_add_value, (t1.f2 - t2.f1) as sub_value
  2  from (select * from temp_calc where f1 = 5) t1,
  3       (select * from temp_calc where f1 = 4) t2;
MUL_ADD_VALUE  SUB_VALUE
------------- ----------
            3         -1
```

**update**:

Адаптировал пример под ваши нужды:

```
SQL> create table temp_calc as select '28.08' as data, 1 as stat, 2 as count from dual where 1=0;
Table created.

SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('28.08', 1,  15);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('28.08', 2,  45);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('28.08', 3, 100);
1 row created.

SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('27.08', 1,  10);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('27.08', 2,  40);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into temp_calc values ('27.08', 3,  95);
1 row created.
SQL>
SQL> select * from temp_calc;
DATA        STAT      COUNT
----- ---------- ----------
28.08          1         15
28.08          2         45
28.08          3        100
27.08          1         10
27.08          2         40
27.08          3         95
6 rows selected.

SQL> select t1.stat, (t1.count - t2.count) as count
  2  from (select * from temp_calc where data = '28.08') t1,
  3       (select * from temp_calc where data = '27.08') t2
  4  where t1.stat = t2.stat;

      STAT      COUNT
---------- ----------
         1          5
         2          5
         3          5
```

Суть в том, что вы разбиваете набор данных на 2 логически связанные группы `t1, t2` (в данном примере на данные для текущего и предыдущего дней). А потом уже выполняете нужные вам подсчеты.

Вариант со смещением является не верным подходом, потому что в Excel записи ("строки") заданы в четком порядке, и обрабатываются они в том же порядке. В СУБД по умолчанию порядок данных не имеет значения. Поэтому вероятно что каждый раз у вас будут другие результаты (в зависимости от порядка следования записей). Можно конечно задать порядок явно, но у вас все равно останется привязка к порядку следования, что чревато проблемами в будущем.

Comment: >>В СУБД по умолчанию порядок данных не имеет значения. Поэтому вероятно что каждый раз у вас будут другие результаты. 

Данное утверждение неверно, результат зависит от сортировки, от построения индекса (они могут быть упорядоченными). Да и в принципе от того, как вы построили запрос...